# Three js OrbitControls rotate camera instead camera target

Tags: three.js

I need to rotate the camera around its center point and not around the target view point. Other behaviour such as panning should stay the same as provided in OrbitControls.

How can I achieve that in Three.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with following code:

```
controls.enableZoom = false;
controls.enableRotate = true;
controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(this.camera.position.x + 1, camera.position.y + 1, this.camera.position.z + 1)
controls.enablePan = true;
controls.panSpeed = 4000;
controls.keyPanSpeed = 26000;
controls.maxDistance = 2000;
```